# Route 53 and GMail - MX redirection

Tags: email, dns, gmail, amazon-route53, mx-record

My domain name use Route 53 like DNS Servie. Is there a way to handle email for my domain ? Example: admin(at)mydomain.com pointing on a Gmail address ?
Is it mandatory to use Google App and pay for that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

No it's not necessary to use Google Apps for this. There are multiple methods to redirect mail.

1. Run a mail-server, by far the most complex but it's free and you are in total control.
2. Amazon WorkMail is cheaper than Google Apps but you still have to pay for it.
3. Mailgun is a great service and is probably the easiest to get running and it's free if you don't send/receive much mail. Check out this guide to get started: https://renzo.lucioni.xyz/mail-forwarding-with-mailgun/

There are many, many others, way too many to list but I think this is a representative sample.

Comment: Doesn't look like mailgun lets you define routes on a free account anymore